# Solution to Equation $Ax=f$ in Hilbert Space

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

> **Question.** Let $H$ be a separable Hilbert space with complete orthonormal basis
>   $\left\{u_{k}\right\}_{k=1}^{\infty}$, let
>   $H_{n}:=\text{span}\left\{u_{1},\ldots,u_{n}\right\}$, and let
>   $P_{n}:H\rightarrow H$ be the orthogonal projection onto $H_{n}$.
>   Suppose that $A:H\rightarrow H$ is bounded, linear and let $f\in H$.
>   If, for all $n\geq 1$, the equation
>
> $$P_{n}Ax_{n}=P_{n}f$$ has a solution $x_{n}\in H_{n}$ such that
>   $\left\|x_{n}\right\|\leq\alpha\left\|P_{n}f\right\|$, where
>   $\alpha>0$ is independent of $n$, show that $Ax=f$ has at least one
>   solution $x\in H$.

I am quite stuck on this question and am looking for a hint or a suggestion to get me on the right path towards obtaining a solution as much on my own as possible.

My first thought was to suppose we had a solution $x$ and then deduce its form through its Fourier coefficients $\langle{x,u_{k}}\rangle$. But then I realized the solution may be not be unique, so this approach was unlikely to yield anything. My next thought was some sort of iterative argument that gives a Cauchy sequence in $H$ whose limit $x\in H$ is a solution to $Ax=f$; but I am not sure how to set that up.

Comment: I don't know if it helps you at all, but observe that $P_{n}Ax_{m}=P_{n}(P_{m}Ax_{m})=P_{n}P_{m}f=P_{n}f$, for all $1\leq n\leq m$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Since $\|x_n\|$ is bounded, there is a subsequence $(x_{n(k)})_{k\geq 1}$ that converges weakly to some $x\in H$. Show that this $x$ is a solution.

Comment: Byron, do you have any intuition for the specificity of the hypothesis $\left\|x_{n}\right\|\leq\alpha\left\|P_{n}f\right\|$ for all $n$? It would seem that uniform boundedness of the $x_{n}$ together with $A$ bounded suffices.

Comment: @MattRosenzweig I agree, the boundedness of $(x_n)$ and continuity of $A$ is enough.